# Selecting cells in one datagridview highlights cell in other Datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am working with a windows form that will hold multiple instances of the **DataGridView** class. When I attempt to select cells in one grid I seem to get a highlighted cell in the other grids. The extra highlighted cells will not be copied if I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but it is misleading. I assume this is do to some issue with the on click event.

Here is a picture of what it looks like:

[image: Windows Form Picture]

Comment: do you have the DataGridViews bound to the same DataSource? You haven't showed us any code or anything to help us deduce why you're seeing the described behavior.

Comment: Yes, I did. I do not expect to be doing this in the finished product. I gave the data grids separate data sources and the issue went away. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the discussion in the comments, OP's issue was resolved by removing the bind to the same object via the DataSource property.